# How to compare number against an interval? ( x > (1,10))

Tags: c, if-statement

How to compare one number against an interval.

Is there any way to shorten this expression:

```
if ((x%10) == 1 || (x%10) == 2 ||  (x%10) == 3 || (x%10) == 4 ) // ... till number 9.
```

Comment: Is that example actually what you need? You can collapse the entire line ("up to 9") to `if (!(x % 10))`.

Comment: That code isn't really comparing a number to an interval...

Comment: @Jongware Thanks! That's what i needed. I know this is basic but I'm a beginner programmer so I will never ask the same question again.

Comment: @Jongware: `if (x % 10 != 0)` is IMHO clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `x` is an integer, there are only 10 possible values. And the only one not checked, 0, is also the only false integer.

```
if (x % 10)
{
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this:

```
if(!(x%10)) {

}
```